# QGIS Gazetteer Plugin connection to internal database

Tags: qgis, python, postgis, gazetteer

A few posts on here mention that the Astun QGIS-Gazetteer-Plugin could be adapted to reference a PostGIS database. Has anyone done this adaptation and could share it? I want to use a gazetteer stored in a PostGIS database, but don't want to have to create a webserver.

Comment: The structure/syntax of the gazetteers looks quite simple. I don't think it would be too much work to make a request to a local or networked database directly, instead of via a webserver. https://github.com/AstunTechnology/QGIS-Gazetteer-Plugin/tree/master/gazetteers

Comment: I admit it looks like not a lot of work, but I don't know Python so was hoping someone else would have done it already and could share it!